# How i can get all the users' responses before updating the list item inside my MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, ms-flow

I have the following MS Flow:-

[image]

[image]

and i have a SharePoint list with an Approvers field as follow:-
[image]

Currently i got this scenario:-

1. let say i create a new item >> set the Approvers fields to UserA & UserB.
2. then both users will get an approval request.
3. but when the first user Accept the request >>  the status for the item will be changed to Resolved..

**While** what i am trying to achieve it to wrap all the users' responses and then update the status, as follow:-

1. if all users Approve then the status will be set to Resolved
2. if all users Reject then the status will be set to Closed
3. if some users approve while the other reject, then the status will be set to "Partially Approved"..

**so i do not want to update the status until all users provide their responses...**

so can you help on how i need to modify my flow to implement the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this with the following steps:

1. Declare an Array variable to collect **[Outcome]** from all approvers
2. Within the [Apply to each] loop, use [Append to array variable] action to append the **[Outcome]** to the variable
3. Outside the [Apply to each] loop, apply the business logic to the values in the array to come up with the **Final Status**, and then update the list with [Update Item] action

### Screenshot showing my test case

[image]

### Outcomes from all Approvers

[image]

---

### The expression to determine the Final Status

```
if(and(contains(variables('varApprovalStatus'), 'Approve'),contains(variables('varApprovalStatus'), 'Reject')), 'Partially Approved',if(and(contains(variables('varApprovalStatus'), 'Approve'),not(contains(variables('varApprovalStatus'), 'Reject'))), 'Approved','Closed'))
```

You can test the logic separately as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

**The Final Status for this example**
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable reply,.but on the final step how i can access the Array to know what is inside it ?

Comment: I will  post the logic for the final status little later

Comment: ok thanks for this